# How to efficiently create a CSR row_index vector in python?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create a [CSR matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) with `m` rows, `n` columns, filled with zeroes and ones (at most one per column). I have a numpy array `idcs` with indices where my 1s are located, ranging from `x` to `n`.

My first approach to create the `ROW_INDEX` vector was something like :

```py
ROW_INDEX=np.zeros(m+1)
for i in idcs: ROW_INDEX[i+1:]+=1
```

Unsurprinsingly though, this is rather slow. I then tried the good old space for speed swap :

```py
ROW_INDEX=np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: i>idcs[j],(m+1,n),dtype='uintc')
ROW_INDEX=np.sum(ROW_INDEX,1)
```

However, `m` and `n` both are at 10^5 so the above code raises a `MemoryError` - even though the large matrix is technically only boolean.

I feel like I missed something obvious here. Anyone has a smarter solution, or should I just increase memory ?

End purpose is to create a `PETSc.Mat`, hopefully in parallel, starting from something like `B=petsc4py.Mat().createAIJ([m, n],csr=[ROW_INDEX,COL_INDEX,V])`. I've found little documentation on the subject, any help on that front would also be welcome.

Comment: `idcs` is an array of row indices? how do you know what the column indices are?

Comment: Yes `idcs` is row indices. `COL_INDEX=np.arange(n,dtype='int32')` so I didn't think it important to mention it, but if you think there's a smarter way to go about this...

Comment: Can you demonstrate with a small example, say a (10,10) array?

Comment: `from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix` and `csr_matrix((np.ones(idcs.shape, dtype=bool), (idcs, COL_INDEX))).indptr` (this will give you your index pointer array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this?

```
ROW_INDEX=np.zeros(m+1)
np.add.at(ROW_INDEX, idcs+1, 1)
np.cumsum(ROW_INDEX, out=ROW_INDEX)
```

Comment: That looks even better than the solution mentioned in the comments above, thanks !